# Printing directly from a server

Tags: php, vb.net, server

I have a client system that cannot install printer drivers, however, it can pass data over to a database on a server, I was wondering what would be the best way to be able to call a print function and have all of the drivers and everything run server-side. 
Is this possible in something like PHP, I wrote an executable in ASP.net however, i keep getting an "access denied" Exception

Comment: Have you tried searching? Searched google using "vb.net get hdd smart data". First result. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3577b7a-ea4b-4c90-a3e9-31a9b621469b/accessing-hard-drive-smart-data-from-vb?forum=vbgeneral You can trim down the excess code to suit your needs if you want of course.

Comment: I'v tried that, copying that but it dosen't want to run

Comment: Ah yes sorry - I didn't check the code. It was badly written. I have re-written it , but on my computer, because of permissions problems I get an access denied error regarding the query and I cant test it fully. So I shouldn't really post it as an answer.